# Sharing PHP-CGI between Apache and NGINX

Tags: php, apache, nginx, fastcgi

I've been running most of my PHP apps on my website on a fastcgi backend, served by NGINX. I have a new application which seems pretty well integrated with Apache; it's heavily dependent on dynamically written .htaccess files, for example. I'm working on modifying it to work natively with NGINX, but that's not yet ready. In the meantime, I was going to have NGINX proxy all connections to that path straight to Apache, and let Apache handle it.

However, I'm on a memory limited VPS, and I'd rather not run one set of PHP-CGI processes for NGINX (with their own APC cache) and another for Apache (using more memory for *their* APC cache). Has anyone had any luck sharing PHP between the two?

mod_ fcgid doesn't appear to support using already running servers, so I tried mod_ fastcgi. This seemed to work at first, but was sucking up quite a lot of memory (committed -- it was growing, not just static). Worse, I couldn't get the DirectoryIndex line in my apache configs to work with mod_fastcgi!

I added

```
    AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php
    FastCgiExternalServer /var/www -host 127.0.0.1:9000
```

to my Apache config, and all .php pages are processed, but a path like http://example.com/foo/ doesn't server /foo/index.php! If I remove FastCgiExternalServer, then it does find the index.php, but of course just shows it as text.

I'm assuming it's because DirectoryIndex is processed after FastCgiExternalServer, but I have no idea how this can be changed.

Comment: You can post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem solved. The trick was to use the following lines

```
FastCGIExternalServer /var/www/fast-cgi-fake-handler -host 127.0.0.1:9000
AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp5 .php
Action application/x-httpd-fastphp5 /fast-cgi-fake-handler
```

The relative path in Action + the full path in FastCGIExternalServer did it!

Comment: What does the rest of your config look like? Inserting the above lines in my Apache config doesn't work.

Comment: can you please explain more? I'm trying to get apache22+mod_fastcgi to work as well without any luck... I got it to work w/ default virtualhost but since FastCGIExternalServer is shared between multiple hosts how would you share it?